# Find numbers in file with grep

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I have a file with numbers, from 1 to 25.

How to find how many times each number occurs in this file?

I am using shell script to do it, so grep makes sense for me:

```
grep char -o filename | wc -l
```

But, I have a problem. In this sequence :

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
11,22,33,44,55,66
11,11,11,1,1,1,1
```

This command will find number 11 4 times, great ! This is an accurate answer.

But, will find number 1 13 times ! And number 1 just occurs 5 times.

So, the answer I am trying to find is: How to tell to grep that 1 is different of 11, and 2 is different of 22, and so on?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `-w` in the `grep` command.:

```
$ grep -wo 1 file | wc -l
5
```

This way, it will just match full words and for example `13` won't be matched when looking for `1`.

From `man grep`:

> **-w, --word-regexp**
>
> Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.  The
>   test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of
>   the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character.  Similarly,
>   it must be either at the end  of  the line or followed by a non-word
>   constituent character.  Word-constituent characters are letters,
>   digits, and the underscore.

Comment: This didn't work for me on OSX (probably it is due to older grep version)

Comment: I use Mavericks (10.9) and the grep version is 2.5.1-FreeBSD and it does work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use word boundaries around search pattern:

```
grep -o '\<1\>' file | wc -l
5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat filename |sed 's/,/\n/g' |sort -n |uniq -c
```

The `sed` statement replaces all the commas so now you have a stream consisting of one number per line. The result is `sort`ed numerically and then counted using the `uniq` utility

You're welcome.

```
~# cat filename |sed 's/,/\n/g' |sort -n |uniq -c                    
      5 1
      1 2
      1 3
      1 4
      1 5
      1 6
      4 11
      1 22
      1 33
      1 44
      1 55
      1 66
```